# Classic asp and integrated mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp-classic, iis-7.5

Is it possible to run classic asp page in integrated mode of IIS7?

I need it for integrating our legacy asp application with new asp.net mvc application.
I have seen seen several examples with web.config:

```
  <add name="classic-asp"
      path="*.asp"
      verb="*"
      type="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
      resourceType="File"
      preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you able to access your server desktop?  http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis

Answer (score 0):

You can not run Classic ASP(VBScript) and ASP.NET/MVC using same application pool.
You will have to create separate folders for each part or at least one as virtual folder for classic asp and assign to it application pool as non-managed code.

Main reason for this because as you clearly stated in your question - both using different ISAPI filters: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll for MVC or NET part and it will not handle Classic asp as you expect it to.

For that you need C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\asp.dll

Comment: Yes you can run classic asp files alongside .net in the same folder as long as you have classic asp enabled in the first place.  They don't need their own app pool

Comment: @John only true if you're not in integrated mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914928/classic-asp-running-in-integrated-pipeline