# Classic asp Request Form error 80004005

Tags: asp-classic

I having problem when trying to post data to my ASP file with integrated pipeline.

ASP CODE:

```
<%
Response.Write request.form("StatusDate")

%>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="myASPFile.asp" method="post">
StatusDate: <input type="text" id="StatusDate" name="StatusDate"><br>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

the page will show :error '80004005'

When I change the integrated mode to Classic Code, the request form is working.

What is the setting that I have missed out in integration mode in order to do the request form for post data

Comment: I don't know if this is your scenario, but maybe this link can help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/63a8f191-9472-4231-b5c6-c8ee7c1e4d28/classic-asp-page-with-requestform-throws-error-80004005-when-iclaimsprincipal-is-null-or-user-is?forum=Geneva

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classic ASP running in Integrated Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914928/classic-asp-running-in-integrated-pipeline)